# How to make under-construction sprites have blueprint graphics?

Tags: unity, c#, shaders, sprites, graphic-effects

In my game, every placeable object and structure will only be placed as a blueprint, which the characters will then automatically build.

An example from "RimWorld":

Objects placed as blueprints:

[image: blueprints]

Objects when finished:

[image: finished]

My initial thought was a shader of some sort, where we'd take the thickest black lines and convert that into the blueprint outlines. Then, a blue transparent background would be added. However, I have no prior experience with shaders so I don't know how to do this.

Is shader even a good option for this?

Other than the mentioned option, I'm open to all ideas on how to implement this.

**EDIT**:

First time ever working with shader graph, here's my result:

[image: shadergraph]

I've used a random sample dirt texture, but the concept is the same. The darkest colors (blacks) on the texture should be extracted. I've completed that process, and you can see the final result. However, those pixels need to be colored light blue (as the outline), and the background needs to be colored dark blue (as the background of the blueprint). I've tried to do this in many ways but failed.

**BONUS QUESTION:** Is it possible to apply said shader to only certain tiles on my tilemap? I don't want to have a separate tilemap just for blueprint objects.

Comment: You've identified two different kinds of difficulty: technical obstacles, and tedious drudge work. Which form of difficulty is more palatable for your team to take on and maintain is a judgement call you can make, much better than strangers like us who know nothing about your team, production timeline, or other goals.

Comment: I'm the only person working on this game and I'd much rather get advice on how to "work smarter, not harder". I've updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Do you have an example of what your objects look like?  Are they identical to RimWorld's style or do you have your own variation that the shader should work with?

Comment: They are going to be identical to RimWorld's style. I'd adapt my sprites so black lines could somehow be recognized and easily turned into a blueprint.

Comment: @DMGregory I've edited the answer to show what I've attempted. The remaining process seems like it would be simple, but I have no idea how to do it nor could I find anything online. Any chance you could help me with this?